# Inventory management in LaTeX

Tags: tables, counters

##### Hello there!

I decided to write a D&D campaign journal using latex, and its going very well so far. Recently an idea came up to my mind, that is to add an inventory management so i can have information of what i have in hand and where everything came from (using hyperlinks and such).

Is there any packages that can be taken advantage for this purpose?

If there isn't any packages, my idea is to use counters, create functions to add and remove itens on the go, as well as a display method. Is that possible?

The inventory itself is a dictionary having only tag-name and quantity.

---

The source of inputs (adding and removing itens) shaw be commands inserted inside the journal entries, where an information like this:

> `...I found 3 pieces of gold inside a chest...`

...would be rewritten like this:

> `...I found \InventoryEntry[gold][3]{3 pieces of gold} inside a chest....`

hypertargeting `3 pieces of gold` and creating the `gold` value inside the dictionary

---

As for the `\tableofcontents`-like command, it would display an `index`-like table displaying: Name, Quantity and page numbers hyperlinking to the referenced entries

Comment: Hm, can you please edit your question and add some examples of what you'd call "inventory"? And also indicate, where it comes from? Thanks